# Ist die Aussage "es geht an" eine Redewendung oder was?

Tags: standard-german

Guten Tag, alle. In letzter Zeit habe ich die am 22. April,2023 gesendete "logo!" gesehen, um Deutsch zu üben. Und darin gibt es eine Aussage also "Im Fastenmonat sollen Muslime so oft es geht an ihren Gott."

Ich möchte wissen, ist "es geht an..." eine Redewendung oder was? Was bedeutet "es geht an"? Ich habe auf DWDS-Wörterbuch durch "es geht an" oder "gehen" geklickt. Aber ich habe nichts gefunden. Es gibt nur Erklärungen über "es geht um".

Comment: Der Satz ist unvollständig. Die kürzesten Korrekturen wären "Im Fastenmonat beten Muslime so oft es geht an ihren Gott." oder "Im Fastenmonat sollen Muslime so oft es geht an ihren Gott denken." Mit dieser Korrektur hätte sich die Frage vielleicht nicht gestellt.

Comment: Das witzige hieran ist, dass „es geht an“ eine Redewendung ist, nämlich in negierter Form „es geht nicht an, dass …“

Answer (score 4):

Der Satz lautet:

> Im Fastenmonat sollen Muslime so oft es geht an ihren Gott – sie nennen ihn Allah - denken und zu ihm beten.

Ich teile den Satz mal in seine Satzteile auf. Ich schreibe jeden  Satzteil in eine eigene Zeile und übersetze ihn wörtlich ins Englische.

> Im Fastenmonat (*during the fasting month*)
> sollen *(should)*
> Muslime *(Muslims)*
> so oft es geht *(as often as possible)*
> an ihren Gott *(of their god)*
> -- sie nennen ihn Allah -- *(-- they call him Allah --)*
> denken *(think)*
> und zu ihm beten. *(and pray to him)*

Ich hoffe, das macht es klar. Der Teil "so oft es geht" gehört zusammen, ebenso der Teil "an ihren Gott", aber es sind getrennte Teile, die beide das Verb "denken" näher bestimmen.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is incomplete.

> Im [...] sollen [...] so oft es geht an ihren Gott - sie nennen ihn [...] - denken und beten.

It's an inserted phrase "they call him [...]" before the verb follows.

Comment: To make it clearer to the OP: so oft es geht — as often as possible; an ihren Gott denken — (to) think of their god.